# Auth Provider in Salesforce flow

Tags: salesforce

Question from a new sales force user. My company wants me to make a flow to sent data threw an API whenever an Account is updated. So far, I have the external service and the record-triggered flow all set up. The ES is connected to a named credential which has Auth provider set up to it. However, whenever I debug my flow and run it, it says I am unauthorized to make the API calls. Is there something special I have to do to get my Auth token from my Auth provider when using a flow?

I thought the auth provider connected to the named credential would automatically grab the access token but that doesn't seem to be the case